# Formik Being Re-rendered When A File Is Selected

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, formik

I'm trying to add an image upload field but whenever I select a file, the whole form is being re-rendered.

useFormik is as follows:

```
const { values, handleBlur, handleChange, touched, handleSubmit, errors } =
    useFormik({
      initialValues: {
        userName: userName,
        name: name,
        lastName: lastName,
        password: password,
        ownerId: ownerid,
        url: url ? url : "",
      },
      validationSchema: AgentSchema,
      onSubmit: onSubmit,
    });
```

The form element itself is:

```
<input
          type='file'
          name='url'
          accept='image/*'
          onChange={(e) =>
            setFieldValue('url', e.currentTarget.files[0])
          }
        />
```

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59743666/17968627) and using useState hook to set file first and handle this issue during submit but no luck, every action re-renders the form or the component. When I try useState hook outside of the form just to test, re-render problem doesn't go away but file selection is successful, so in that case instead of the whole component, only Formik part gets re-rendered, which is bizarre. Trying any other solution results fails to choose file.

What I'm trying to accomplish is selecting file without losing other form data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was when I was filling form with initial values, the query that gets the initial data was refetching on window focus. When I select a file, I was going back to the form, hence window focus again. Problem solved by adding this following option to the query that fills the form beforehand: `refetchOnWindowFocus: false`